# Primefaces UI issue with Gallery Film strip

Tags: jsf, primefaces, gallery

I am implementing a gallery using PrimeFaces with the component `p:galleria`,  everything works as expected but the footer (Film Strip) is shown twice.

[image: Screenshot - Unexpected UI]

By the way, if I close and then reopen the modal dialog which contains the gallery the Film Strip displays correctly.

[image: Screenshot - Expected UI]

More Information:

- The gallery is contained in a modal dialog
- PrimeFaces version: 5.3
- Browsers: Chrome and IE

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved this behavior with the next workaround...

I had to open the external dialog using onclick() event instead of oncomplete()

Greetings!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I already have `onclick` but the filmstrip still gets doubled.

A working workaround for me is to update the galleria when the dialog is shown, e.g.

```
<p:commandLink onclick="PF('popup').show();" update="galleria"/>
<p:dialog id="popup">
    <p:galleria id="galleria"/>
</p:dialog>
```