# Images wrongfully repeating in p:galeria

Tags: jsf, primefaces, image-gallery

I'm in trouble using primefaces image galleria.
Sometimes the filmstrip is displayed multiple times, sometimes not. 
[Galleria printscreen](https://ibb.co/M90zHBf)

The images are obtained dynamically by a Servlet class.
I have already debugged the code and the list of images is correct, without repeating the items.

How can I prevent images repetition?

galleria.xhtml

```
<p:galleria id="myGalleria" 
        value="#{myBean.imageList}"
        var="item" 
        effect="fade" 
        autoPlay="false" 
        panelWidth="540"        
        showCaption="true" 
        widgetVar="myGalleria">     

    <p:graphicImage width="520" 
                    id="img"
                    title="#{item.description}"
                    value="/imageServlet/show?id=#{item.id}" 
                    cache="false" />
</p:galleria>
```

ImageServlet

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String id = request.getParameter("id"); 

    if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(id)) {

        try {

            byte[] dados = myService.getImageData(id);
            if(dados != null) {

                String fileName = id.concat(EXTENSAO_ARQUIVO);

                response.setHeader("Content-Type", getServletContext().getMimeType(fileName));
                response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(dados.length));
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

                // configuracoes de cache
                response.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache, no-store");
                response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
                response.setHeader("Expires", "-1");

                InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(dados);
                OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

                IOUtils.copy(in, out);

                if(in != null) {
                    in.close();
                }
                if(out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
            }           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: log
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

MyImage class

```
public class MyImage {
   private String id;
   private String description;
}
```

MyBean class

```
public class MyBean {
   List<MyImage> imageList = myService.getImageList();
}
```

Comment: You forgot some code: here MyBean.imageList is always an empty list.

Comment: @StephaneM 
I edited my question by changing that part of the code responsible for getting the list of images. The list of images is loaded correctly.

Comment: I improved your tile. Please look at the differences and read [ask] about 'good/bad' titles

Comment: What is your PrimeFaces version?

Comment: @Kukeltje Primefaces 6.2

Comment: Try 7.0, just try (not saying you should use it in production) so we are sure it is not something that is fixed in the mean time (although it might  not even be a bug in PF)

Answer (score 1):

this might be a duplicate of [Primefaces UI issue with Gallery Film strip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46607778/primefaces-ui-issue-with-gallery-film-strip/55902179#55902179), see my workaround there:

```html
<p:commandLink onclick="PF('popup').show();" update="galleria"/>
<p:dialog id="popup">
    <p:galleria id="galleria"/>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: This change minimized the problem but did not resolve it. Thank you